# create filedatastore of mat files filtering files by filename pattern in matlab

Tags: matlab, datastore

Is it possible to create a filedatastore of mat files filtering files by filename pattern?
So far I got this:

```
fds = fileDatastore(dir_save,'ReadFcn',@load,'FileExtensions','.mat','IncludeSubfolders',true);
f=1;
while hasdata(fds)
        disp(num2str(progress(fds)*100) 
        dataarray = read(fds);
        if ~isempty(strfind(fds.Files{f},myPattern))
            %% do somthing
        end
        f=f+1;
end
```

But some mat files I will not be using are really large and therefore slow down the process.
I cannot move all the files to 1 directory because my directory structure is like:

```
d01/file1.mat
d01/myPatternFile.mat
d01/othefile.mat
d02/file1.mat
d02/myPatternFile.mat
d02/othefile.mat
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards in the call to [fullfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html). 
Using an example from the documentation of [fileDatastore](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.filedatastore.html):

```
% No filtering
>> fds = fileDatastore(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','demos'),'ReadFcn',@load,'FileExtensions','.mat')
fds = 

  FileDatastore with properties:

                       Files: {
                              'E:\MATLAB64\R2018b\toolbox\matlab\demos\accidents.mat';
                              'E:\MATLAB64\R2018b\toolbox\matlab\demos\airfoil.mat';
                              'E:\MATLAB64\R2018b\toolbox\matlab\demos\airlineResults.mat'
                               ... and 37 more
                              }
                 UniformRead: 0
                     ReadFcn: @load
    AlternateFileSystemRoots: {}

% Filtering for .mat files starting with "w"
>> fds = 

fileDatastore(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','demos','w*'),'ReadFcn',@load,'FileExtensions','.mat')
fds = 

  FileDatastore with properties:

                       Files: {
                              'E:\MATLAB64\R2018b\toolbox\matlab\demos\west0479.mat';
                              'E:\MATLAB64\R2018b\toolbox\matlab\demos\wind.mat'
                              }
                 UniformRead: 0
                     ReadFcn: @load
    AlternateFileSystemRoots: {}
```

---

For checking over different folders, use two wildcards:

```
>> !mkdir d01
>> !mkdir d02
>> !touch d01/file1.mat
>> !touch d01/myPatternFile.mat
>> !touch d02/file2.mat
>> !touch d02/myPatternFile.mat
>> fileDatastore(fullfile(pwd,'d*\myPattern*'),'ReadFcn',@load,'FileExtensions','.mat')
ans = 

  FileDatastore with properties:

                       Files: {
                              'H:\Documents\56133896\d01\myPatternFile.mat';
                              'H:\Documents\56133896\d02\myPatternFile.mat'
                              }
                 UniformRead: 0
                     ReadFcn: @load
    AlternateFileSystemRoots: {}
```

Comment: nice solution! IF my files where all within one directory, but I have them spread over different subfolders... And actually because of that I got an error: `Wildcard '*' characters must not be used with IncludeSubfolders`

Comment: See my edited answer. You can just use two wildcards in a similar way.